# Can I notch the wide side of a 2x4 stud?

Tags: electrical, framing, garage

Can I safely notch 3/16" from the wider side of two load bearing 2x4 studs to fit a flush mounted electric sub panel between them? The stud cavity is slightly too narrow to fit the panel where I want to mount it. This is in a detached garage with 12' ceiling.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not an engineer here, but I would sister in another 2x4 outside of the cavity on the right side.

Trim out the 3/8 needed for the panel, from the inside of the right 2x4 and block about a foot above and below the panel.  (I know it will get drilled for cables anyway, just extra stiffness.)